# World map: filtering by 'subregion' removes many regions

Tags: r, ggplot2

See below - I don't understand this behaviour. I can successfully filter by `region`, but not by `subregion`. This happens both with and without fortifying the object `WorldData1`. It also saves like this to file. Any ideas?

```r
library(tidyverse)
WorldData1 <- map_data('world') %>% filter(subregion != '') 

# I am using no characters as filter, but this also happens when putting in a subregion, e.g. 'Alaska'

#> 
#> Attaching package: 'maps'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     map
ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = WorldData1, map = WorldData1,
           aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region)) 
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x, y
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
#>  os       macOS Mojave 10.14.3        
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         

#>  tidyverse   * 1.2.1   2017-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution - I feel it's worth keeping this question because it points towards an interesting behaviour of `filter` ([see related thread here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3196))

Filtering by subregions removes any NA in subregion, removing the necessary rows for creating the polygons for the countries. Explicitly including NAs in the filter command helps:

```r
library(tidyverse)
WorldData1 <- map_data('world') %>% filter(is.na(subregion)| subregion != 'Alaska') 

ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = WorldData1, map = WorldData1,
           aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = region))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x, y
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>